# Change link in menu on condition

Tags: menus

I have website, where I want to change link in menu, if I'm on this page, example:

On frontpage link in menu is: `http://example.com/#blog`
On blog page link in menu is: `http://example.com/blog`

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes - this is possible.  Are you able to write CSS?  JS is another option.  I will post an answer outlining one of many possible approaches.   To write the CSS version you will need to know how to inspect elements and identify the correct classes.

Comment: @jdm2112 I have full access to my server, so I can change everything.

Comment: And I know too, how to inspect elements and edit it ;)

Comment: CSS option below should work.  Let me know if you have any trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to do this involves using the CSS `display` property.  Simply add two instances of your menu link, one with the home URL and one with the URL for all other pages.   The idea is to hide the one you don't want on pages you want the other to show, never showing both on any page.

In your CSS, add two rules that target these particular menu items. Each menu item will be an `<li>` element with multiple classes.  Each will have a unique class that looks something like `menu-item-1982`.

Assuming your theme has the WP body classes enabled (verify by inspecting the HTML `<body>` tag) you can show/hide the correct menu item with code similar to this:

```
.home .menu-item-1982 { display: inline-block; }
.home .meun-item-1983 { display: none; }
```

This example will show menu item 1982 on the home page and hide 1983.

To hide 1982 on all pages but the home page, and to show 1983 on all pages but the home page, add a default state reversing the display property without the `.home` body class prefix.